# I need to run database load test, each time a different user has to login

Tags: jmeter, load

I need to run database load test, each time a different user has to login and execute the same query. Is there a way the jdbc configuration can be read from a csv file?

I have a JDBC sampler with one query. But i need to run 100 iterations of the query execution, but each time, the database credentials needs to be read from a csv file.

In the JDBC Configuration, the database url will stay the same, but each iteration should take database username and password from the csv file.

Comment: the different user is for login your application and not for login the database connection, right?

Comment: HI, its not to the application. I need multiple logins to the database itself..

Comment: What are you trying to simulate? In your production environment you probably don't have many users for the same database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 options on how you can proceed:

1. Create 100 [JDBC Connection Configuration](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Connection_Configuration) elements and assign different `Variable Names` to them. As per documentation:

   > The name of the variable the connection is tied to. Multiple connections can be used, each tied to a different variable, allowing JDBC Samplers to select the appropriate connection.

   So you will be able to switch `Variable Name` in the JDBC Request sampler according to your test scenario use cases.
2. Switch to [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) where you can use different credentials for each request.

   - [Groovy: SQL](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/sql/Sql.html)
   - [Groovy: Working with a relational database](http://groovy-lang.org/databases.html#_executing_sql)
   - [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)